# Handling a game clock across multiple devices in real time

Tags: android, timer

I'm a designer/developer in the National Collegiate Dodgeball Association, and we wanted to develop an Android app for officials to use on the court during matches. It's small, it won't be used by more than 10-15 people per week, only a few months out of the year.

One feature we're struggling with: We want to handle a game clock that is consistent and interactive across 3-4 devices, communicating over a basketball court (about 60'/20 m). How can I achieve this / what can I look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm a designer/developer in the National Collegiate Dodgeball Association

To save everyone the Google search: http://ncdadodgeball.com/ :-)

> We want to handle a game clock that is consistent and interactive across 3-4 devices, communicating over a basketball court (about 60'/20 m). How can I achieve this / what can I look into?

If your question is "what radio technology will work for that range?", it is too far for Bluetooth or NFC. WiFi should be OK barring too many competing signals in the facility. Whether you go WiFi Direct (so there is no need for a common access point that all devices are configured for) or traditional WiFi is up to you. Cellular may work, but that is somewhat dependent upon the facility, and you would probably have to have a server somewhere that would be the central coordination point, rather than a pure peer-to-peer approach.

Comment: Looks like WiFi direct supports one-to-many devices. Between cellular and WiFi direct, what would be more reliable? My first thought is clock timing, but it could extend to the central device in the p2p network running out of battery.

We set up a group of 4 devices, establish a game clock, and have any device start/stop/edit that clock. If we had to go cellular, I would think that using Node js on maybe Heroku or a similar low capacity service would be the way to go. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Zigmister: "Between cellular and WiFi direct, what would be more reliable?" -- I can't answer that. Reliability is dependent on a lot of factors, mostly environmental. If you have the engineering time, you might consider supporting both, so you have a fallback option. "I would think that using Node js on maybe Heroku or a similar low capacity service would be the way to go" -- I agree that capacity will not be your problem. Whether you need a custom Web service or can use something off-the-shelf (XMPP, RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, etc.) would depend upon implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have no affiliation with any of the companies, organizations or community groups referenced in this answer. With that out of the way, let's get started.

I assume that you want to have very precise timing since the games have strict rules and everything has to play out smoothly. My suggestion isn't Android specific per se, but it might be a good starting point depending on how much you're willing to experiment to get the whole thing working.

### Timing Object

There's a *W3C Multi-device Timing Community Group* that advocates standardization of the timing object. Although it's mostly discussed with `HTML5` in mind, the technology should work well for an `Android` application too. Here's an explanation taken from the [specification draft](http://webtiming.github.io/timingobject/):

> The timing object is a local object that may be used by Web clients to
>   ensure precisely timed operation as well as flexible timing control.
>   If multiple timing-sensitive components take direction from the same
>   timing object, their behaviour will be precisely aligned in time
>   (synchronized). Crucially, this is also the case in distributed
>   settings. A central motivation for the timing object is that it may be
>   connected to an online timing resource. This way, the local timing
>   object is a gateway to precisely timed operations, both in
>   single-device and multi-device scenarios.

[image: This image is taken from the Timing Object draft]
*This image is taken from the [Timing Object draft](http://webtiming.github.io/timingobject/). Copyright © 2015 the Contributors to the Timing Object Specification, published by the Multi-Device Timing Community Group under the W3C Community Contributor License Agreement (CLA).*

There are already many possibilities for handling timing in a single web page (or an application) but this specification would allow it to work synchronized on multiple web pages (or apps taking advantage of the functionality).

My suggestion for you (if you're adventurous and not afraid of diving deep into something that's not widely used yet, nor mature **yet**) would be to take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/webtiming/timingsrc) created by the  *Multi-Device Timing Community Group* and study the [documentation](http://webtiming.github.io/timingsrc/doc/index.html).

The part you're most interested in, is the `Timing Providers` section of the documentation. There's an API (product) called [`Shared Motion`](http://webtiming.github.io/timingsrc/doc/shared_motion.html) that provides an *online timing service for web agents (IP-connected clients)*.

> Shared Motion solves multi-device timing and turns timing into a local challenge.
>
> ...
>
> If your application already uses the timing object for single-device timing, turning it into a multi-device application is trivial. All you need to do is to plug an online timing provider into the timing object.

To sum it up, this solution is by no means the simplest one, but it's worth looking into if you're looking for precise and synchronized timing for multiple devices. You'll also have to figure out how to make use of `Timing objects` on Android but it shouldn't be too complicated in the end.

Comment: Trying to answer this kind of question myself, I ran into too many possibilities but nothing concrete for a synced timer, interactive across different devices. I also like standards. ``Shared Motion`` looks promising. Thanks for the suggestions.